# Keras "SavedModel file does not exist at..." for a model retrieved from an online URL

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras, transfer-learning

Keras "SavedModel file does not exist at..." error occurs for a model retrieved from an online URL and never manually saved at any local directory.
The code ran just fine for as long as I've been working on it before but I reopened the project today and without changing anything it now gives me this error.
[Code Snippet & Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GvU8.png)

Comment: Please add the code snippet as text, and also add the text of the error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it myself. Simply visit the file directory the error mentions and delete the folder with the random numbers and letters in it. Rerun the program and it'll properly generate the files needed.